# Time.unscaledDeltaTime still counting even when app is in background

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, timer, game-engine

I just use a generic code to count how long the player has been playing in the update function:

```
float time;

void Update()
{
    time += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
}
```

Here is the problem:

When I press the home button on my android device or browse past applications the timer still counts. So if I wait a while in home or in other apps screen and come back to the game, the timer includes time even when I have been out of the app. The game state stays exactly how it was before but only the timer changes.

What could be the reason and how can I prevent the timer from counting when the application does not have focus?

Comment: Which function do you perform this: `time += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;`? What happens when you use `Time.deltaTime`?

Comment: the code is preformed in update. i have in game abilities that slows down time i dont want the timer to be effected by that.

Comment: I know that's why people use unscaledDeltaTime. I wasn't gonna tell you to use it as your solution. What happens you use it? Remember that asked two questions, You only addressed one.

Comment: Are you asking me if this bug still happens if i use delta time or are you asking in game preoblems. I am sorry i cant understand your question.

Comment: I am asking you if this bug still happens if you use delta time.

Comment: just tested it. nope it looks like the bug isnt the case when deltatime is used the game stopes just like its supposed to. any idea how i could make it so that the slow down time abiliy does not effect the timer while using deltatime?

Comment: That's what I was trying to know before leaving answer. Check the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal value from `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` is usually around `0.01687395`.
When `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` is used, it is still adding up in the background when you shift focus out of the app. Once you return back to the app, the value of `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` will be the x seconds you were out of the app.

For example, if you shift focus out of the app for 15 seconds then return back, the output of `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` will be 15 in the first frame then jump back to around `0.01687395`. The `Time.deltaTime` variable does not have this problem but it is not an option too since changing `Time.timeScale` affects it.

The solution is to use `OnApplicationFocus` and `OnApplicationPause` to detect when the application is running again then skip adding `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` in the first frame as that first frame is when `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` is really the x seconds you were out of the app.

Here is a working solution:

```
public Text text;
float currentTime = 0;
private bool skipFrame = false;

void Update()
{
    //Add only when we don't need to skip frame
    if (!skipFrame)
    {
        currentTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        text.text = currentTime.ToString();
    }

    //We need to skip frame. Don't use Time.unscaledDeltaTime this frame
    else
    {
        skipFrame = false;
        Debug.LogWarning("Filtered accumulated Time when Paused: " + Time.unscaledDeltaTime);
    }
}


void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
{
    //Enable skipFrame when focoused in app
    if (hasFocus)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Has focus");
        skipFrame = true;
    }
}

void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    //Enable skipFrame when coming back from exiting app
    if (!pauseStatus)
    {
        //Debug.Log("UnPaused");
        skipFrame = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: couple of questions am i supposed to use currentTime in all my time time based events (or just put the float value i use instead of currentTime) or do i need to add currentTime to my timer in update? im confused to how i can implement this to my code.

Comment: Nothing else you have to do. Just copy and paste this into your code. I renamed your `time` to `currentTime` and use  `currentTime` as a total time the app has been opened. That's it.

Comment: i tried using the same code for a countdown timer (its supposed to count down from 15) but just putting a "-" between timer and unscaledDeltaTime did not work. any tip to how?

Comment: The-same code should work for count down. `currentTime -= Time.unscaledDeltaTime;` If you can create a new question with your code and describe count-time problem, I will take look at it.